# React pass children to sibling

Tags: reactjs, architecture, react-redux

I have run into a situation where it seems I need to pass the children of one component over to another that is a sibling of the original. This doesn't sit well with me as it seems to go against what I've learned is the proper hierarchy and communications channels in React. I need the components to render as siblings due to styling issues, but I'd like to have a logical grouping of components for developers utilising my component.

In short I have some buttons and some of these buttons display a drop-down menu. Like a toolbar of sorts. I want the menu to pop up in a modal like way and so I don't want to place a sub-div next to the button. Instead I want it to render below the buttons and just swap its components with whatever menu is currently active.

Here is how I envision the rendering to look:

```
<ul>
  <li><button>Triggers some action elsewhere</button></li>
  <li><button>Button with menu</button></li>
  <li><a href="...">Link</a></li>
  <li><button>Button with menu</button></li>
  <li><button>Triggers some action elsewhere</button></li>
</ul>
<div class="menu-container">
  Menu content goes here
</div>
```

Since the buttons are 1-1 linked with a menu I want the developer to work with the components like this:

```
<Nav>
  <NavButton text="Triggers some action elsewhere"/>
  <NavMenu text="Button with menu">
    <Link to="/">A link</Link>
    <Box>
      ...
    </Box>
  </NavMenu>
  <NavLink>
    <Link to="/">Link</Link>
  </NavLink>
  <NavMenu text="Button with menu">
    <Link to="/">A link</Link>
    <Box>
      ...
    </Box>
  </NavMenu>
  <NavButton text="Triggers some action elsewhere"/>

  {/*
    This component is dynamically inserted by <Nav/> at this position.
    It is responsible for rendering a floating menu and controlling its
    behaviour.
  */}
  <FloatingMenu></FloatingMenu>
</Nav>
```

The `<Nav>` component would then swap the content of the `.menu-container` div based on whether a menu was open or not.

EDIT!

I forgot to mention that there is a separate component here that the developer doesn't see. The `<FloatingMenu>` component is dynamically inserted by `<Nav>` and not actually part of the set of children that the developer will write. It is responsible for rendering the actual menu div and controlling its behaviour. So what I'd like to do is move all children from the currently active `<NavMenu/>` component into the `<FloatingMenu/>` and empty it out if no menus are active. At least that was my original idea.

/EDIT!

Can this be done? Am I over complicating or misunderstanding something? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where does the information on what items to show/hide come from? You could have a state (maybe Redux or just native React state) and create one more component to render menus.

Comment: Sorry, there is a component for rendering the menu in there. I've updated the question. The idea I had was to pass children of <NavMenu> to it when it was active. Not sure if that is a good idea though. I do use redux for state management so another issue would be how to track the active item in the state.